# Does flushing DNS cache clear search history

Tags: dns

I do not want to lose my search history (i.e entering a phrase in the URL bar and the most related searches) because I use that to access all my websites with ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Your DNS cache is run by your operating system.  Your browsing history is run by your browser.  Neither is related to the other.

Comment: A browser may keep its own DNS cache as well, though Chrome seems to always set the TTL to 1 minute.